# Dimension of quotient of ideals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, ideals

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra, $I$ be a closed two-sided  ideal in $A$, and  $J$ be a closed  two-sided ideal in $I$ such that there is no ideal  between   $I$ and $J$. Can we see $dim(\frac{I}{J})<\infty$?

Y. DOMAR in "On the ideal structure of certain Banach algebras",  proves a lemma like this question with the following difference:

$A$ is commutative, $J$ is a  two-sided ideal in $A$ and he shows $dim(\frac{I}{J})=1$

Comment: Do you know about the ideal structure of B(H)? This provides an immediate noncommutative counterexample. One place to learn more is by looking at some of the articles cited in www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~drygier/ivmrt2014/slides/laustsen.pdf

Comment: What about above question when $A$ is commutative?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}_p$ is a commutative Banach algebra over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and one can set $J=0$ and $I=\mathbb{C}_p$ for a counterexample in the commutative case...

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I am (1- infinitesimal) sure that the OP is only doing Banach algebras over the complex field; I assume you're taking about p-adic Banach algebras?

Comment: Oh rotten luck :-) What is this pathological non-non-archimedean complex numbers field anyway? Is there an infinite complete field extension of it? That would presumably be an example in the commutative case. Can you just take some random transcendental extension and then complete it somehow?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard In the land of complex Banach algebras, the only one which is also a field is C itself (Gelfand-Mazur theorem). The second idea seems to lead towards a notorious open problem: does there exist a unital commutative Banach algebra over C with no non-trivial proper closed ideals?

Comment: What do you think about $dim(\frac{I}{IJI})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we allow $A$ to be noncommutative then there are well-known natural counterexamples. For instance one can look at $A=B(E)$ for various Banach spaces $E$. I imagine that there should be counterexamples of the form $A=L^1(G)$ but I do not know this for sure.

There are "silly" commutative counterexamples obtained by defining $I$ to be an infinite-dimensional Banach space with zero product, $J=\{0\}$, and setting $A$ to be the unitization of $I$.